# Processing signal from QAudioProbe

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyside, pyside2

I am trying to receive the signal from QAudioProbe's audioBufferProbed signal. I have tried the connect function but I am not using it properly. I want to print the signal values to the console while the media plays.

I am using Python3 and PySide2 (Qt 5.15).

```
#!/bin/python3

from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QAudioProbe
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl, QCoreApplication, QObject, Signal
import sys


def main():

    app = QCoreApplication()
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample2.mp3")
    content = QMediaContent(url)
    player.setMedia(content)
    player.setVolume(50)

    # probe = QAudioProbe()
    # probe.setSource(player)
    # QObject.connect(probe, Signal(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)), processProbe)

    player.play()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)

def processProbe(probe):
    print(probe)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's the [very] old style of Qt connections. Try it with `probe.audioBufferProbed.connect(processProbe)` [OT: are you the same Aaron from music.stackexchange?]

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, and no I am not the same Aaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the syntax of PySide2 (and also PyQt5) is `sender.signal.connect(receiver.slot)`:

```py
#!/bin/python3

from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QAudioProbe
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl, QCoreApplication, QObject, Signal
import sys


def main():

    app = QCoreApplication()
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/ubuntu/Downloads/sample2.mp3")
    content = QMediaContent(url)
    player.setMedia(content)
    player.setVolume(0)

    probe = QAudioProbe()
    probe.setSource(player)
    probe.audioBufferProbed.connect(processProbe)

    player.play()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)

def processProbe(buff):
    print(buff.startTime())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the sound loudness from the data in processProbe?

Comment: It seems that all the data returned is the same. How could I turn this into something useful?

Comment: const quint16 *data = buffer->constData<quint16>();

This is what I need to do I think. How can I rewrite this for PySide2? Not sure how to import or use quint16